# Draw polygon with equal sides and angles

Tags: java, swing, polygon, bresenham

I am using Bresenham line algorithm in order to draw a simple line.
I need help with using this algorithm to create a polygon with equal sides and angles.
The sides will be the line created by the Bresenham algorithm, but how do I use the created line in order to draw a polygon with X number of sides and equal angels?

Here is the line algorithm I am using:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.01) {          
            Point2D p = between(p1, p2, t);
            g2d.fillRect((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), 5, 5);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public Point2D between(Point p1, Point p2, double time) {

        double deltaX = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
        double deltaY = p2.getY() - p1.getY();

        double x = p1.getX() + time * deltaX;
        double y = p1.getY() + time * deltaY;

        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your (i-1)th edge of N-sided polygon ends at point x(i-1), y(i-1) and is rotated at angle a(i-1) relative to horizontal axis. So the next edge will be rotated at the angle:

```
a(i) = a(i-1) + pi - (N-2)/N*pi
```

and will end at the point:

```
x(i) = x(i-1) + L * cos(a(i)) 
y(i) = y(i-1) + L * sin(a(i))
```

where L is length of one edge. So iterating i from 1 to N and connecting points, you will get your polygon.

If you want to build your polygon using its center point x(c), y(c) and radius R of containing circle, calculate point coordinates in the following way:

```
x(i) = x(c) + R * cos(2*pi*i/N)
y(i) = y(c) + R * sin(2*pi*i/N)
```